How can I create stored procedure with multiple arguments and multiple insert statements?
I created this procedure but this will insert one row only
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_HOSPITAL_PROGRAMS 
    (HOSPITAL_ID IN INT, 
     SAMPLE_ID IN INT,
     PROGRAM_ID IN INT) 
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HAJJ_HOSPITAL_PROGRAMS (ID, HOSPITAL_ID, SAMPLE_ID, PROGRAM_ID)
    VALUES (seq.nextval , HOSPITAL_ID, SAMPLE_ID, PROGRAM_ID);
END;

But I need to give multiple values with in the procedure like this
HOSPITAL_ID from 1 to 20 
SAMPLE_ID   from 1 to 10 
PROGRAM_ID  from 1 to 6 

And the INSERT I need it like this :
ID   HOSPITAL_ID    SAMPLE_ID     PROGRAM_ID  
--------------------------------------------
 1       1              1            1
 2       1              1            2
 3       1              1            3
 4       1              1            4
 5       1              1            5
 6       1              1            6
-----------------------------------------
 7       1              2            1
 8       1              2            2
 9       1              2            3
 10      1              2            4  
 11      1              2            5
 12      1              2            6
---------------------------------------

Each HOSPITAL_ID has 10 SAMPLES from 1 to 10, and each SAMPLE has 6 PROGRAMS from 1 to 6.
How can I do that with in the stored procedure?
Thank you

you need to use a collection

or simply call the procedure in a loop

You don't need a stored procedure but generating rows in select statement of hierarchical query along with an insert statement like this :
INSERT INTO hajj_hospital_programs
SELECT seq.nextval,
       TRUNC((level-1) / (10 * 6) ) + 1, 
       MOD( TRUNC((level-1) / 6 ), 10) + 1, 
       MOD((level-1), 6) + 1
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 20 * 10 * 6; -- will generate 1200 rows

COMMIT;

Demo
